# SELECT DISTINCT name but return all data

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a table full of cars:

Say there are 4 dodge vipers, there would be 4 entries in the database, all are identical apart from the carID.

```
   carID | carname | carmodel | colour   |  reg
--------------------------------------------------
    1    |  viper  |  dodge  |   red     |  123
    2    |  viper  |  dodge  |   red     |  124
    3    |  viper  |  dodge  |   red     |  125
    4    |  viper  |  dodge  |   red     |  126
    5    |   R8    |  audi   |   blue    |  127
    6    |   R8    |  audi   |   blue    |  128
```

When a User searches for cars, I want to display only one dodge viper. However I want to pull all the info from that row, and every other distinct car.

So the output I desire is:

```
   carID | carname | carmodel | colour  |  reg
--------------------------------------------------
     1   |  viper  |   dodge  |  red    |  123
     5   |   R8    |   audi   |  blue   |  127
```

If I do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM cars
```

it pulls back all entries.

```
SELECT DISTINCT carname FROM cars
```

Only pulls back one of each, but I only have the car name.

Is there such a:

```
SELECT * FROM cars ORDER BY DISTINCT carname
```

Or something similar?

Comment: please provide some sample data and desired output.

Comment: As @raheelshan mentioned, sample data and desired output would be needed to help you, as it's hard to tell what you're asking. What I fail to understand is why you even need to use `DISTINCT` if you want all the values any way? Do you want all the car ID's concatinated into one string in one row in your final result (eg. `carIDs = 1,2,3,4 | carname = viper ...`)?

Comment: And seeing you sample data i would like to ask what is the need of inserting same data 4 times

Comment: Erm, there are physically 4 cars, so when booked out, every booking is assigned a carID, so a booking has an specific car, I should of added car registration in the sample data to show this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return he `carId`, then you can use the following which will return the `min(carid)` for each identical `carname`, etc:

```
select min(carId) as carId, carname, carmodel, colour
from cars
group by carname, carmodel, colour
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d480a/2)

You will see that I placed the `carId` in an aggregate function this is to make sure that MySQL will always return the expected value for the `carId` column. When you do not `GROUP BY` or aggregate the items in the SELECT list, you might return unexpected results. (see [MySQL Extensions to `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html))

From the MySQL Docs:

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. ... You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values the server chooses.

Comment: If he doesn't care about the `carId` he returns, is there a specific reason to use `max()` on it?

Comment: @h2ooooooo If they want to return a `carid` in the result and they are distinct on each row, then you would have to use an aggregate function on the column so then you could return it along with the grouping.

Comment: [You wouldn't **have to**. You can, but you don't have to. Check this fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc7f6/1/0)

Comment: @h2ooooooo While MySQL does not require that, there is no guarantee what `carID` is going to be returned if you do not use an aggregate function.  MySQL selects the first value it finds, this however is incorrect in every other database...if a column appears in a select list it must be in a group by or an aggregate function.

Comment: That is completely correct - it could be any `carID` in the match (however, it probably wouldn't matter which as they all have the same data), and `min/max` would make sure of it, but if it doesn't matter, wouldn't it simply be a waste of resources (albeit, sure, it's a very minimum amount of resources that'd be required).

Comment: I agree with @bluefeet and using optiomized solution and making it your habbit is much better than only workig solutions

Comment: @h2ooooooo I am writing my answer to work on all database products because while that syntax works in MySQL the group by requirement should be properly enforced with the [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand, do you mean grouping ?

```
SELECT MAX(CarId) as carId, carname, carmodel, colour FROM cars GROUP BY carname, carmodel, colour;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT carname, otherCol1, otherCol2... FROM cars
```

[SQLFiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97b4e/1)

As You editted the question and want to display your car_id, above solution is no good.
Here you go:

```
SELECT MIN(carId) AS carId, carname, carmodel, colour
FROM cars
GROUP BY carname, carmodel, colour
```

MIN or MAX SUM Whatever you use is just a projection...perception you can say

Comment: This will give the same results as SELECT DISTINCT * FROM cars

Comment: Just make sure carID is not in the column list.